# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'guid' on string '#partnercode'

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the HTML header of a PHP file, I am loading a .js file that contains something like the following:

```
methods: {
init: function() {
  this.hookEvents();
},

hookEvents: function() {
  this.hookEvent("change", "#partnercode", CceModule.Org.EditCRQuestions.partnercode_selected);
},
```

},

```
  partnercode_selected: function() {
    var selectedOption = $(this.val());
    if (selectedOption == 0) {
      $('.partnerSelected'.css('display', 'none'))
    } else {
      $('.partnerSelected'.css('display', 'block'))
    }
  },
}
```

The HTML/PHP code is ...

```
    <label>Partner Code</label>
  <select style="width: max-content" name="partnercode" id="partnercode" class=".partnercode" data-mandatory='true'>
  <option></option>
  <?php
    foreach($this->partnerCodes as $aPartner){ ?>
  <option value="<?=$aPartner["partnerid"]; ?>"><?=$aPartner['partnerid']?></option>
  <?php } ?>
  </select>
```

I am getting an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'guid' on string '#partnercode'"
I am at a loss. I use the same process in many other situations with no issues. There has to be something I am doing differently, but I can't spot it.

Comment: Read the error, don't ignore it. The error tells you what line is causing the error.

Comment: The only place where `#partnercode` exists is in the line `this.hookEvent("change", "#partnercode",` and you haven't shown us the code for this function.  It's impossible to say why it's doing this or what it's expecting here.  Also you have a `.`  in `class=".partnercode"` which you should probably remove

Comment: The id in the HRML SELECT element is "partnercode," thus, the #partnercode in the hookEvent references that id attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I knew it was something stupid. My "partnercode_selected: function() " function was outside of the scope of "methods:" The closing curly bracket for the "methods:" block was above the function that was supposed to be enclosed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).